# How to upload Csv File from Dedicated Server to NonDedicatedServer and then perform the following task

Tags: java, web-services, csv, spring-mvc

Given 2 Servers

1)X is a LinuxServer(Dedicated to some specific task)

2)Y is a WindowsServer(NonDedicated One.Which can be used to perform any task.

My task is:

a)Make Connection with DedicatedServer via FTP.

b)Upload a CSV File from Dedicated Server to NonDedicated Server via FTP

c)Read THE CSV File.

d)Hit HTTP Request from the collected CSV File data.

Solution:
1)While figuring some ways I could only implement how to make connection with Dedicated Server via FTP:

Below is my code:

```
FTPClient ftpclient = new FTPClient(); 
try {
            ftpclient.connect(ftpServerAddress);
            result = ftpclient.login(userName, password);
            if (result == true){
                    System.out.println("Logged in Successfully !");
            } 
            else{
                    System.out.println("Login Fail!");
                    return;
            }
```

> Can any one guide me how to perform b) c) d) task.
> It will be also helpful if there is any other approach through which I can do Communication between 2 Servers.
>
> I can use Java,Spring framework and WebServices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the apache commons Net API to read file from the dedicated server via FTP.
Use this link to get more idea :
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example

Once you have the file data you can use Spring Rest Template to make an http call like below. or you can refer this link to get more info (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html)

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
String uri = "http://localhost:8080/multipart-http/inboundAdapter.htm";
Resource s2logo = new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/samples/multipart/spring09_logo.png");
MultiValueMap map = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
map.add("company", "SpringSource");
map.add("company-logo", s2logo);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(new MediaType("multipart", "form-data"));
HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(map, headers);
ResponseEntity<?> httpResponse = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, null);
```